# Tomcat 9 UI Stop Command not Triggering ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, war

I am starting and stopping an application via Tomcat 9 UI and am getting stuck threads. While trying to investigate, I am not seeing a ContextClosedEvent triggered to stop an executorserivce.

I've tried implementing ApplicationListener and using the annotation @EventListener.

I then tried using a @PreDestroy annotation and even a Runtime shutdown hook. None of these get called when I click "stop" in the Tomcat UI, causing stuck threads.

Does anyone know why Tomcat will not trigger any context clues that the application was shutdown? Is there some other trigger I should use to identify the application was closed?

Answer (score 0):

I determined that the Tomcat UI will close an application context and trigger ApplicationEvent ContextClosedEvent when the "Stop" button is clicked. It will not trigger the ContextClosedEvent when clicking the "Undeploy" button.

To properly remove an application from Tomcat, you'll want to click stop and then undeploy. To date, I've not found this documented anywhere so hopefully this helps someone else.